# How to get R_THEVENIN in Wheatstone bridge?

Tags: resistors, resistance, thevenin, wheatstone-bridge, bridge

In the simplification of a Wheatstone bridge with Thevenin's theorem when we calculate the R<sub>Thevenin</sub> as in the schematic. How to explain in another way that  the resistor R1 and R3 are in parallel and not in series?

[image]

Comment: Mouh, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

R1 and R3 are connected between the same two nodes (the red and the blue). Points 2 and 3 are connected by a 0 Ω circuit element so they are, in effect, the same node of the circuit.

To expand further:

- When viewed from AB the R1 and R3 are in parallel.
- When the external loop is replaced by a voltage source (as it normally would in practice) then, when viewed from the voltage source, R1 and R3 would appear to be in series as would R2 and R4. You then have (R1 + R3) || (R2 + R4).

Comment: A question people ask me is if the current goes through R1 it would be the same as R3. This point confuses me

Comment: Your circuit has no power source so there is no flow of current. I think you are now asking a new question and recommend that you open a new question for this topic. Add a clear diagram that shows your power source and what direction you think the current will flow.

Comment: I'm not asking an other question it's juste à confusion why the two resistors are not in series

Comment: Look at your Figure 3 redrawing of the circuit from the point of view of A and B. Are R1 and R3 in parallel or in series?

Answer (score 0):

> *How to explain in another way that the resistor R1 and R3 are in
> parallel and not in series?*

R1 and R3 are in parallel by visual inspection: -

[image]

Comment: A question people ask me is if the current goes through R1 it would be the same as R3. This point confuses me

Comment: It depends what is connected to A and B

Comment: I am still confused how to understand that the two resistors are not in series

Comment: Being in parallel does not exclusively stop them being in series and vice versa. They are in parallel and series @MouhKramo <-- sometimes that happens and sometimes one can find it is impossible to say that two components are parallel or in series.

Comment: But when we take the series case it gives another value for the R_thevenin

Comment: You are not explaining things properly. You asked about how to show that they are in parallel and that has been answered. How you have calculated R_thevenin is unknown to me and everybody except you. If you want to ask a new question ask how R_thevenin can be calculated but, you must show the work you have done to calculate it yourself or that new question will be closed as "homework with no attempt at a solution".

Comment: I think that the only way to understand this  It is to base myself on the practical method when we replace the load by a test generator

Comment: I have no idea what you mean @MouhKramo

Comment: finding Rthevenin with the experimental method consists in removing the load and putting in its place a test voltage generator